# Pyramid Unit Test Sending Parameter

Tags: json, unit-testing, pyramid

I have a Pyramid web-application that I am trying to unit-test.

In my tests file I have this snippet of code:

```
anyparam = {"isApple": "True"}
@parameterized.expand([
    ("ParamA", anyparam, 'success')])
def test_(self, name, params, expected):
    request = testing.DummyRequest(params=params)
    request.session['AI'] = ''
    response = dothejob(request)

    self.assertEqual(response['status'], expected, "expected response['status']={0} but response={1}".format(expected, response))
```

Whereas in my views:

```
@view_config(route_name='function', renderer='json')
def dothejob(request):
    params = json.loads(request.body)
    value = params.get('isApple') #true or false.
```

However, when I'm trying to unit-test it, I am getting this error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

However, when I make the same request via POST via web-browser it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

By doing `testing.DummyRequest(params=params)` you are only populating `request.params`, not `request.body`.

You probably want to do something like:

```
request = testing.DummyRequest(json_body=params)
```

Also, you may want to use directly `request.json_body` in your code instead of `json.loads(request.body)`.

Comment: If I do that way there is a attribute error: NoneType' object has no attribute. When I tried to debug None is being sent as parameters. I also tried both - request.json_body and json.loads(request.body), even placed them in try/except.

Comment: OK, I don't really have time to debug this, but you could try to do `testing.DummyRequest(body=json.dumps(params).encode('utf-8'))`, or `request = testing.DummyRequest()` then `request.body = json.dumps(params).encode('utf-8')`.